# Image Upload Error "Type Error occurred when creating object" Magento 2.4.1

Tags: php, magento, magento2

In my custom form I have a option Image upload. Without image upload form submit without any error. but when i user image upload code and submit my form get error

> Type Error occurred when creating object:
> MKF\CustomApplication\Controller\Index\Submit\Interceptor, Argument 4
> passed to MKF\CustomApplication\Controller\Index\Submit::__construct()
> must implement interface Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface,
> instance of Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory given,
> called in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_new\generated\code\MKF\CustomApplication\Controller\Index\Submit\Interceptor.php
> on line 14

Code controller **Submit.php**

```
namespace MKF\CustomApplication\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use MKF\CustomApplication\Model\FormModel;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;


use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Submit extends Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $FormModel;


    //file upload
    protected $_objectManager;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_filesystem;
    protected $_fileUploaderFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        FormModel $FormModel,

        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory
    )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->FormModel = $FormModel;

        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        // print_r($this->getRequest()->getPost());

        // exit();

        try {
            $data = (array)$this->getRequest()->getPost();

            //print_r($data); exit();
            //print_r($file['owner_nid']['name']); exit();

            $this->UploadImages();


            if ($data) {
                $model = $this->FormModel;
                $model->setData($data);
                $model->setData('owner_nid', $file['owner_nid']['name']);
                $model->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__("Data Saved Successfully."));
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e, __("We can\'t submit your request, Please try again."));
        }
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;

    }


    private function UploadImages(){

        $files = $this->getRequest()->getFiles();



        $mediaDir = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();
        $mediapath = $this->_mediaBaseDirectory = rtrim($mediaDir, '/');


        if (isset($files['owner_nid']) && !empty($files['owner_nid']["name"])){
            try {
                $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'owner_nid']);
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
                $path = $mediapath . '/MKF/CustomApplication/';
                $result = $uploader->save($path);



                if (!$result) {
                    throw new LocalizedException(
                        __('File cannot be saved to path: $1', $path)
                    );
                }
                $imagePath = $path.$files['owner_nid']["name"];

            }
            catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
            }

            //print_r($data['owner_nid'] = $imagePath); exit();

            return $imagePath;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you switch to developer mode and delete the generated folder